# CodeIgniter Ignited Datatables combine 2 query fields as 1 column

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable

I have a table `Person` with fields `LastName`, `FirstName` and `MiddleName`.

I would wanted to display in datatable as one column the `LastName, FirstName MiddleName`

Is it possible? How?

Comment: I have no answer for your problem, but I'd strongly suggest to read [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) and rethink your database model.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do `SELECT CONCAT(LastName, ", ", FirstName, " " , MiddleName ) as Name FROM Person`. This will concat all names in one column named Name. Second blank " " is to set a gap between First and Middle Name.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use MySQL CONCAT function to make it happen

```
SELECT CONCAT(LastName,' ', FirstName,' ',MiddleName) AS PersonName From Person;
```